# Leer y guardar saltos de línea de un textarea en React

Tags: html, reactjs

Estoy utilizando React.js para guardar los datos insertados por el usuario (en un `textarea`) a MongoDB. Quisiera entender cómo interpretar los saltos de línea para luego, al hacer un `get` a la base de datos, poder mostrarlos en un `<p>` ya sea reemplazando un `\n` por un `<br/>`, o como en verdad se deba hacer. 
Sería genial si me pueden contestar con la solución, desde ya muchísimas gracias.

Esto es lo que "se me ocurrió" pero no funciona, ya que me imprime literal un `<br/>`:

```
componentDidMount = async() => {
    try {
        const {data} = await Axios.get(`${this.URI}/get/info`);
        var text = data.info;
        var newText = text.replace("\n", "<br/>");
        this.setState({
            info : newText
        })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

render(){
    return (
        <div>
            <p>{this.state.info}</p>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No necesitas cambiar los `\n` por `<br />`, puedes solucionar esto mediante CSS usando la propiedad `white-space`, por ejemplo, puedes crear la siguiente clase:

```css
.parrafo {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

Y aplicarsela al nodo `<p>` de tu componente, de forma que tu código quedaría así:

```
componentDidMount = async() => {
    try {
        const {data} = await Axios.get(`${this.URI}/get/info`);
        var text = data.info;

        this.setState({
            info : text
        })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

render(){
    return (
        <div>
            <p className="parrafo">{this.state.info}</p>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Te dejo aquí un pequeño CodePen con el que he probado esto: https://codepen.io/HorusGoul/pen/RwWyQwz

---

Por cierto, veo que utilizas `var`, en mi canal de YouTube tengo un video que te puede ayudar a mejorar como programador en JavaScript: https://youtu.be/umG8-BmfBiU

Comment: Todavía no lo he probado, pero de todas formas muchísimas gracias por tu respuesta. En unos momentos ni bien pueda lo probaré.
Una pregunta: ¿Debería de comunicarle al usuario que los saltos de línea los escriba de forma explicita con un `\n`?

Comment: No es necesario que el usuario haga eso!

Comment: Ya lo he probado, ¡funciona de maravilla!.. Gracias por tu respuesta, no conocía esa propiedad de css, es buenísima.